# Rails 3 - problem with a sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, model, group-by

I have following sql query in Rails 3 syntax:

```
    variab = Model.joins(:photo).where('photos.user_id = ?', user).group('model.photo_id').count
```

In the `Models` table I have these data:

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | photo_id |  created_at          | updated_at         |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 31 |      210 | 2011-09-16 14:38:22 | 2011-09-16 14:38:22 |
| 32 |      210 | 2011-09-16 14:38:22 | 2011-09-16 14:38:22 |
| 33 |      211 | 2011-09-16 15:03:26 | 2011-09-16 15:03:26 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

And I try to get the value **2** - I need to get count of unique **photo_id** data.
But if I will use the sql query above, so the output is ** 21022111** - I don't understand, what this number mean... I would assume the output should be *2*, but I don't understand, why not...

If anyone could help me with this problem, I would be really glad... Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Record is returning the photo_id/count pairs, i.e. photo_id 210 count 2, photo_id 211 count 1.

If you want to count the number of distinct photos for a given use then try:

```
Model.select(:photo_id).where(:user_id => user.id).count(:distinct => true)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for your reply. This example generate me this query: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `model`.`id`) FROM `model` LEFT OUTER JOIN `photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `model`.`photo_id` WHERE (user_id = 2)` - and this gives me in my script the result **0**, but in terminal in mysql the number **3**. But the right output should be 2.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your model. Is the user_id on the models or photos table? If its on the photos table then the where clause in the answer is wrong.

Comment: If the user_id key is on the photos table then you would need to do it something like this: Model.select(:photo_id).joins(:photo).where('photos.user_id = ?', user).count(:distinct => true)